# Selecting Title in selenium webdriver but it doesn't select

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

When selecting a hotel and giving the information.  The select drop down is unable to select the title.  I used selectByVisibleText,index and value, still it doesn't select the title.
(WebSite link :  https://www.trivago.in/?aDateRange[arr]=2018-06-16&aDateRange[dep]=2018-06-20&aPriceRange[to]=15145&aPriceRange[from]=500&iPathId=84780&aGeoCode[lat]=19.075983&aGeoCode[lng]=72.877655&iGeoDistanceItem=0&aCategoryRange=0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5&aOverallLiking=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5&sOrderBy=relevance%20desc&bTopDealsOnly=false&iRoomType=1&cpt=8478003&iIncludeAll=0&iViewType=0&bIsSeoPage=false&bIsSitemap=false&)

Okay So Manually i'll Tell you what the above code do

1.Here it searches for mumbai and select the dates from 16 June to 20th June 2018

```
driver.findElement(By.id("horus-querytext")).sendKeys("Mumbai");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ref='searchButton']")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.className("cal-btn-next")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("cal-btn-next")).click();
//Selecting June 16 2018
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td//time[@datetime='2018-06-16']")).click();
//Selecting June 20 2018
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td//time[@datetime='2018-06-20']")).click();
```

2.I then use mouse action to select my room as "Double room"

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement doubleRoom = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='js-fullscreen-hero']/div/form/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/button"));
Action pointOver = builder.moveToElement(doubleRoom).click().build();
pointOver.perform();
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

3.Here i select the hotel and check the pics of the hotel

```
//Selecting a Hotel
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='js_item_3486926']/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/h3")).click();
//Previewing Photos
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='tabs__item tabs__item--active']//button[@class='tabs__label']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gal-mob__arrow.gal-mob__arrow--trailing")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gal-mob__arrow.gal-mob__arrow--trailing")).click();
//closing the hotel window
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn--small.btn--tertiary.slo-btn--close")).click();
```

4.In this piece of code i select my hotel

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='js_item_3486926']/div[1]/div[3]/section[2]/div/button[2]")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

5.Once i select my hotel, It will take me to another window to reserve it.

```
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("Parent Window ID is : " + parentWindow);
int count = allWindow.size();
System.out.println("Total Window : " + count);
    for(String child:allWindow)
    {
        if(!parentWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(child))
    {
```

6.Child window is opened here :

```
driver.switchTo().window(child);
driver.findElement(By.id("choose-room-disable")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

7.Clicking on booking button here:

```
//Booking room for two
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-if='!isAppFor.destranet']")).click();
```

Thread.sleep(3000);

8.Another page loads where i have to give my full details:

```
//Email & Phone Number
driver.findElement(By.id("additionalContactEmail")).sendKeys("xyz@123.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("additionalContactMobile")).sendKeys("000000000");
```

9.Now here where the problem lies, this piece of code should select the title. It doesn't do that and as i said earlier I've used selectByVisibleText,index and value, still it doesn't select the title.

```
          //Selecting Title
          driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='paxNum0']/div[2]/div[1]/span/select")).click();
          Select dropDwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='paxNum0']/div[2]/div[1]/span/select")));

          dropDwn.selectByIndex(1);

          Thread.sleep(4000);
         //Name
          driver.findElement(By.id("travellerf0")).sendKeys("Divya");
          driver.findElement(By.id("travellerl0")).sendKeys("Master");
          driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='traveller-dom']/form/div[3]/button")).click();
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          driver.close();
      }
  }
  driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```

Comment: At which step are you exactly stuck? Can you update the question with the _Manual Step_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: I am stuck at the code after this line *********//Selecting Title 
Here it should select the drop down as "Mr." when completing the booking but it doesn't.

Comment: Unable to follow your code to reach to the error prone step. Update your manual steps.

Comment: Hie @DebanjanB I've updated my question step by step.
Number 9 where it doesn't work.

Comment: Unable to follow Step 4 i.e. _select my hotel_. Your `xpath` doesn't resolves. How are you selecting the hotel which opens a new window?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run just last part where you are processing click on the `dropdown element` you would see that it works fine. So your issue is probably not related to 'Selecting title' part.

Here is the code that works just fine and I can see the drop down element being selected:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://hotel.yatra.com/hotel-checkout/dom/hotel/review?ci=YTVG&tenant=TRIVAGO&checkInDate=16/06/2018&checkOutDate=20/06/2018&city.name=Mumbai&city.code=Mumbai&hotelId=00000538&rooms[0].noOfChildren=0&rooms[0].id=0&rooms[0].noOfAdults=2&_rn=46u&roomTypeId=0000240804&ratePlanId=0000937548&utm_content=dCbfGbk24MQ&excludeHotelTax=false&chpFare=0&searchId=6678a1eb-5000-4db2-a3e7-2ac1ea47a1ef");
Select dropDwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='paxNum0']/div[2]/div[1]/span/select")));
dropDwn.selectByIndex(1);
```